# using sed to remove "number"

Tags: bash, sed

I have this xml file

```
</license>
<parameters pca-dim="32"/>
<parameters resize_minpix="100000" npix="100000" ptch="24" step="4" nscale="5" maxscale="4"/>
<parameters notify-classes-removed="1"/>
<parameters grid-regions="1x1,1x3"/>
<feature_extractions>
<feature_extraction id="orh" params="8,4:0.7,0.5:0.4,0.6:0.01"/>
<feature_extraction id="col" params="4:mv:0.4,0.6:0.01"/>
</feature_extractions>
<vocabulary rebuild="IfDoesNotExist" gmm-iter="8" sig-norm-type="l2" sig-norm-pow="0.5"/>
<classifier type="sgd" lambda="1.0E-5" max-iterations="20"/>
<validation name="V1CrossValidation" folds="5" mode="fast" method="modulo" result-file="/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/CshellTest/ScriptTests/temp/V1CrossValidation-results.stats" score-flags="combine,normalize"/>
```

I would like to use sed command to change folds="5" to folds="6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed -e 's/ folds="5"/ folds="6"/g' file.xml
```

You can omit the `g` modifier, it's for general replacement (all occurrences that match will be replaced).

If you want to write to the file rather than print to the standard output, use the `-i` (for in place) option :

```
sed -i 's/ folds="5"/ folds="6"/g' file.xml
```

If OS X, you can use :

```
sed -i '' 's/ folds="5"/ folds="6"/g' file.xml
```

Comment: Is there a space before folds ?

Comment: It has to be this way 
sed -e "s/ folds='5'/ folds='$1'/g"

Comment: In you example code, folds values have double quotes not single quotes. And why are you using a positional parameter in you command (`$1`) ?